# Why take(5) operator in RxJava return all objects

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have problem with `take(5)` operator in rxjava. I don't why 
`subscribe {ui.showLikes(it)}` always return all objects from database. Operator `take()` doesn't work? What I doing wrong? Thx for help.

```
fun downloadLikes(userId: String, skillId: Int) {
    val subscription = apiService.rxListPluses()
            .flatMap {
                localDataSource.savePluses(it)
                apiService.getUserDetails()
            }
            .flatMap {
                localDataSource.rxGetLikeItems(userId, skillId)
                        .take(5)
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                ui.showLikes(it)
            }

    bindToLifecycle(subscription)
}

public Observable<ArrayList<LikeItem>> rxGetLikeItems(String userId, int skillId) {
    return Observable.fromCallable(() -> getLikeItems(userId, skillId));
}
```

Comment: You mistake a sequence of LikeItems with lists of LikeItems. That take will give you no more than 5 `ArrayList<LikeItem>`s.

Comment: OK, now I understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like in the comment, `rxGetLikeItems` emits `ArrayList<LikeItem>`, not `LikeItem`.

So `rxGetLikeItems(your, mum).take(5)` means "take the first five `List<LikeItem>` emitted"

To put it clearer using another example, assume the function:

```
fun getList() : Observable<List<Int>> {
    return Observable.just(listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10))
}
```

If we call `take(5)` on this:

```
getList()
        .take(5)
        .test()
        .assertResult(
            listOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
)
```

we get the first list as an emission.

What you probably want instead is something like `flatMapIterable`:

```
getList()
        .flatMapIterable { x -> x }
        .take(5)
        .test()
        .assertResult(
                1,2,3,4,5
        )
```

Or if you need a list to be emitted:

```
getList()
        .flatMapIterable { x -> x }
        .take(5)
        .toList()
        .test()
        .assertResult(
               listOf(1,2,3,4,5)
        )
```

Note also that it's better to return a `List` rather than an `ArrayList` if possible because of the Liskov substitution principle.

Comment: OK now I understand. Thx for a explanation :)